# Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid. SQLlite

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2012, edmx

I have joined to existed project, and when try to build solution get Error 175: The specified data store provider cannot be found, or is not valid. in few projects. All of that are linked to different edmx files, and in all files all code after `<edmx:StorageModels>` are marked as error.

Example of edmx file:

```
<edmx:StorageModels>
    <Schema Namespace="AWareDBModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SQLite" ProviderManifestToken="ISO8601" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityContainer Name="AWareDBModelStoreContainer">
```

p.s I am using vs 2012

Comment: Have you installed the SQLite provider on your system?

Comment: Seem like yes, sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x64-2010-1.0.94.0.exe from was installed.

Comment: What .Net framework is your project targeting?  That is the .Net 4.0 provider.

Comment: .Net 4 as well, but in edmx header: <edmx:Edmx Version="2.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">

Comment: I would try installing the .Net 4.5 version from the SQLite download page. There is a note in regards toe the x86 version that it is the one that includes the design time components for VS2012: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Comment: Just tried, still the same error(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure that is correct, but I have pasted this line

```
<add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.94.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139"/>
```

to  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config and error disappear

Comment: when you replace it, it gives you a warning"access denied", how did you do that?